# Postgres AWS RDS Database high load during random moments

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

My Postgres database is having a high load during random moments of the each day, and when I reboot it comes back to normal.

The performance insight below shows the queries, the problems that I can see are in DataFileRead e WALWriteLock.

The issue is the same queries run all throughout the day without issues, but at random moments is spikes.

[image]

Below the graph of the last week:

[image]

Comment: This could be related to checkpoints: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html

Comment: "the same queries run all throughout the day without issues"  Do you have verification of this from logging or something, or this just based on what you think your app *should* be doing?

Comment: Yes, through logging, the TOP SQL are all the same throughout the day

Comment: If I am reading the graphs correctly most of the load is `DataFileRead` related to SELECT queries. I would run  the queries manually with `EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to see what they are doing.

Comment: The top events all seem related to IO.  Can you monitor the IO devices directly (independently of the database monitoring)?  Is the throughput going up during the spikes, or is the latency going up but with no change in throughput, or even a decrease in throughput if the latency prevents the work from getting done?  If the load spikes happen randomly, it hard to know if the rebooting fixes the problem, rather than just being coincident with the resolution.

Comment: Yeah, the I/O read time increases with the spikes, but my guess is that it increases BECAUSE of the spikes, because the DB is "slow".